# ListBox not updated when items added to data source

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I have a `ListBox` where items are filtered based on text entered in a textbox (and when enter is pressed):

```
<TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,0,0,20" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=FilterText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
   <TextBox.InputBindings>
      <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=FilterSearchCommand}" Key="Enter" />
   </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
<ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Name="lbItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=lbItems}" Cursor="Hand" Margin="10,10,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Center" MouseLeftButtonUp="UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonUp">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

When ENTER is pressed in the textbox, the following command is executed:

```
FilterSearchCommand = new RelayCommand(() => {
 MyList = new ObservableCollection < MyObject > (MyList.Where(x => x.Title.IndexOf(FilterText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToList());
});

public RelayCommand FilterSearchCommand {
 get;
}
public string FilterText {
 get;
 set;
}
public ObservableCollection < MyObject > MyList {
 get;
 set;
}
```

Basically on entering the command, the ObservableCollection is successfully updated, however the items in the list box remain unchanged.

Any ideas?

Comment: It makes no sense to have an ObservableCollection when you only create new collection instances when the command is executed, but never add or remove elements to an existing collection.

Comment: You are going to have a bit of an issue here - Upon a search, you will overwrite your 'MyList' object. So, once you filter, you cannot un-filter.

You should look into using a [CollectionViewSource](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CollectionView-Tips-MVVM-d6ebb4a7)

Comment: As another note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the ItemsSource Binding is pointless. It has no effect here.

Comment: @TrialAndError - your solution did the trick. Can you add it as an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have a bit of an issue here - Upon a search, you will overwrite your 'MyList' object. So, once you filter, you cannot un-filter. You should look into using a [CollectionViewSource](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CollectionView-Tips-MVVM-d6ebb4a7).

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and in the setter of MyList you will notify the UI that the property is changed. Here's an example:

```
class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyObject> _myList;

    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyList
    {
        get { return _myList; }
        set
        {
            _myList = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just Gave this a try, but no luck - the list box is still not updating

Comment: Can you post some code on how you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Do you set _myList or MyList with the results?